# How to put parentheses around year in list of references

Tags: bibliographies

I am using `apj.bst` together with style `\citestyle{apj}` and with the `\usepackage{natbib}`.

I have made few changing on this style, so that my bibliography appears like this: for example

> Beth, T. and Gollmann, D. 1989. Algorithm Engineering for Public Key
>   Algorithm. IEEE Journal on selected areas in communications 7 (4):
>   458-465.

My question is: how can put parentheses around the year to be appear like this:

> Beth, T. and Gollmann, D. (1989). Algorithm Engineering for Public Key
>   Algorithm. IEEE Journal on selected areas in communications 7 (4):
>   458-465.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Code can be marked by enclosing it in backticks :`\``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

copy the `apj.bat` to `myapj.bst` and then replace the function `format.date` with

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{  year duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * "; set to ????" * warning$
       pop$ "????" }
    'skip$ 
  if$
  " (" swap$ * * ")" *
  extra.label *
  before.all 'output.state :=
  after.sentence 'output.state :=
}
```

put the `myapj,bst` for testing in your documents directory and use

\bibliographystyle{myapj}